Cannot use local IDE instance while migrating to Intellij Platform Plugin 2.*
I develop Intellij idea plugin. Currently I'm migrating to Intellij platform gradle plugin 2.*.
The problem is I cannot use local IDE instance to launch plugin. Once I do so (by switching from "intellijIdeaCommunity" to "local"), my project stops compiling.
This example project illustrates my problem:
https://github.com/evg64/HelloWorldPlugin
The project compiles as is, however if to modify build.gradle.kts by replacing:
intellijIdeaCommunity("2024.3.1")

with:
local("/path/to/my/local/ide/instance")

then I get the following error:
e: file:///.../src/main/kotlin/com/helloworld/actions/HelloWorldAction.kt:3:42 Unresolved reference 'AnAction'

"/path/to/my/local/ide/instance" leads to the following IDE:

What am I doing wrong?
